# How do I actually write acpid event scripts that detect when headphones are plugged in?

Tags: debian, acpi, acpid

I'm using `acpid` to detect when my headphones are plugged in. According to `acpid_listen`, the relevant events are

```
jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
```

I created the file `/etc/acpi/events/headphone_jack` like this:

```
event=jack/headphone.*
action=/etc/acpi/actions/headphone.sh "%e"
```

The event still doesn't trigger if I use `jack[ /]headphone` instead. The script `/etc/acpi/actions/headphone.sh` looks like this:

```
amixer set Master off
```

In other words, every time the headphones are plugged in or unplugged, the volume is muted. This `amixer` command works in the terminal. I restarted the `acpid` service with `sudo /etc/init.d/acpid reload`, but the event still isn't triggering.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Debian 10 ("buster") x64 on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 4th generation.

Comment: The script might need "#!/bin/sh" on the first line, and it must of course be executable.

Comment: I'm embarrassed that I forgot to make the script executable. I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the shebang, but otherwise, your answer is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script might need "#!/bin/sh" on the first line, and it must of course be executable.

It's a not un-common mistake to miss or forget the latter, which is fixed with

```
$ chmod a+x /path/to/script
```

A more exhaustive description of all this is found in the standard manual pages with:

```
$ man execve
```

On Debian systems those manual pages have nowadays been relegated out of the standard collection, and you may need to install them from the `manpages-dev` package with:

```
# apt-get install manpages-dev
```

Note that the package installation requires `root` access, unless you have some other means of installing packages.