# Switch Pulseeffects profiles on headphones connection/disconnection

Tags: flatpak, acpid

this is related to...
[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25776/detecting-headphone-connection-disconnection-in-linux][1]

as the title states, I wanted to switch pulseffects profiles on headphone connection/disconnection. I've referred to the link below for setting profiles via the terminal but these do not work on the pulseeffects flatpack.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200332/how-can-i-toggle-selected-pulseeffects-equalizer-profile-from-command-line

after a bit of googling, I figured out that i could

use, `flatpak run com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects -l <profilename>`
to change the profile as necessary.

I assume that I'll have to use acpid to execute the aforementioned on jack/headphone
plug/unplug events. https://linux.die.net/man/8/acpid. Later, I found this link.

[How do I actually write acpid event scripts that detect when headphones are plugged in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559326/how-do-i-actually-write-acpid-event-scripts-that-detect-when-headphones-are-plug)

...and have now created two events

headphone-jack-plug

```
event=jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
action=/etc/acpi/headphone-jack.sh plug
```

headphone-jack-unplug

```
event=jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
action=/etc/acpi/headphone-jack.sh unplug
```

the script, however exits with status 1 on running `sudo journalctl -u acpid -f`
for both events.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = plug ]; then
flatpak run com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects -l HdPhDlbCnv
elif [ "$1" = unplug ]; then
flatpak run com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects -l DolbConv
fi
```

on redirecting the error to a file i see...

```
error: app/com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects/x86_64/master not installed
```

but running the flatpak command in a terminal works... how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I found an easier solution to achieve this:

Create a preset where all plugins are disabled. Let's say that you call it none like in the image below
[image]

While the headphones are plugged in click on the middle button with a curved arrows icon. This is the preset autoloading button. As long as it is activated while the target device is selected as default the corresponding preset should be automatically loaded whenever this device becomes the default again.

[Source](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/issues/765)